# Simplification involving exponents to base e

Tags: exponential-function

I've found the following expression. It looks really simple - so it's driving me crazy, that I don' get it:

$(e^{3x}).(2)$ is simplified as $2e^{2x}$.

Similarly, $(2x+7).(3e^{3x})$ is simplified as $(6x + 21)e^{2x}$

My problem isn't with where $6x$ and $21$ come from, because the multiplication by $3$ in $3e^{3x}$ seems obvious, what isn't obvious to me is why the $3$ in the superscript of $e^{3x}$ is changed to $e^{2x}$ in both cases. Surely, $ (2). e^{3x}$, just gives you 2 lots of $e^{3x}$, why should the exponent change to $2x$?

The expressions are used in an example of using the Quotient Rule in differentiation:

$$y = \frac{e^{3x}}{2x+7}$$

Set $u(x) = e^{3x}$ and $v(x) = 2x+7$

$$\frac{du}{dx} = 3e^{3x}$$ and $$ \frac{dv}{dx} = 2 $$

then

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(2x+7).(3e^{3x})-(e^{3x}).(2)}{(2x+7)^2}$$

This is then simplified to this

$$\frac{(6x+21)e^{2x} - 2e^{2x}}{(2x+7)^2}$$

and then this

$$\frac{(6x+19)e^{2x}}{(2x+7)^2}$$

Comment: ??? Where did you find that? What is the context?

Comment: $2e^{3x}=2e^{2x}$ implies $e^x=1$ and is therefore only true for $x=0$. Where did you find these formulae? Are you sure you're interpreting them correctly?

Comment: I've added the origional context of the two things to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simplification is completely invalid, and likely a typo. The derivative should be

$$\frac {(6x+19)e^{3x}} {(2x + 7)^2}$$

You can confirm with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive%20e%5E%283x%29%2F%282x%2B7%29) if you want to be sure.